# Using the CLT vs using the standard normal z test formula?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a bit of confusion on this topic. If you were for instance approximating a binomial distribution as normal (Given by N(np, npq)), when would you just use the standard $\bar x-\mu$/$\sigma$ equation and when would you have to divide the bottom also by the square root of the sample size?

As an example, assume a distribution B(100,0.4). It would be ~N(40,24). Would you then proceed to use the formula (using the obtained $\sqrt{24}$ standard deviation using the $\sqrt{npq}$ formula) with the $\sigma$ divided by $\sqrt n$ or just divide by $\sigma$ assuming we just wanted to find the Z score of an arbitrary $\bar x$?

Comment: $\sigma$ relates to a single random variable. $\sigma/\sqrt n$ to an average of $n$ independent random variables.

Comment: But doesn't each binomial "event" imply that there are independent random variables, and so applying the CLT would make $\sigma$ / $\sqrt {n}$ necessary?

Comment: I said single vs. average, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment (continued):**  Here is a plot of $\mathsf{Binom}(n=100,\,p=.4)$ [vertical bars] along
with the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 40, \sigma = \sqrt{24})$ [blue curve].

[image]

Comment: Ok, so my main problem: When applying the CLT to the Binomial (and not the Binomial proportion), why is it exactly that the calculated standard deviation using npq is not further divided by $\sqrt {n}$ as dictated in the ($\bar x$-$\mu$)/($\sigma$/$\sqrt {n}$) classical CLT formula?

Comment: When standardizing to use the normal approximation for a random variable $Y,$ you always subtract $\mu = E(Y)$ and divide by $\sigma = SD(Y).$ If it happens that $Y = \bar X,$ where the $X_i$ are a random sample from a distribution with mean $\mu$ and SD $\sigma,$ then you have $E(\bar X) = \mu$ and $SD(\bar X = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ But that is a _different problem_ than for your binomial $X.$

Comment: Once more--when standardizing $Y$ you subtract $E(Y)$ and divide by $SD(Y),$ whatever $SD(Y)$ happens to be in the problem at hand. It seems you are trying to generalize from the first CLT problem you ever saw. Not all problems are alike.

Comment: Oh ok, so then the second case with the division by $\sqrt{n}$ only applies when specifically applying this to random samples ?

Comment: I gave you the correct rule. Don't try to get me to agree to something you just made up and may not always be right.